# jquery check if text has been enterd and not cleared before active the button

Tags: jquery

I have a form in that I have taken one select options dropdown and another with input text type. Now I want that when someone will fill both the fields then after the add fields button will made active otherwise it will be remain disabled.
The code for my markup along with jQuery like this

```
  <div id="form-wrap" style="width:500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th width="55%">Service Name</th>
        <th width="35%">From Price</th>
        <th width="10%"></th>
      </tr>
          <tr id="template">
            <td id="example" width="55%">
              <select name="service-name" id="service-name" style="width:230px;">
                <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
                <option value="service-1">service-1</option>
                <option value="service-2">service-2</option>
                <option value="service-3">service-3</option>
                <option value="service-4">service-4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td width="45%"><input type="text" name="from-price" id="from-price" /></td>

          </tr>
    </table>    <input type="button" value="+ Add Field" id="add-field" />
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled",true);
  jQuery("select#service-name, #from-price").on("change, keyup, keydown",function() {
  var selectLength = jQuery('select#service-name').val().length;
  var textLength = jQuery('#from-price').val().length;
    if(selectLength > 0 && textLength > 0) {
        jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
      jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

Here its working fine when I am adding values for first time but when I am removing any values( clearing text or dropdown option reset) then the button is still showing in active state?

Live demo can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/u96zT/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for change event. That's enough:

```
jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled",true);
jQuery("select#service-name, #from-price").on("change",function() {
var selectLength = jQuery('select#service-name').val().length;
var textLength = jQuery('#from-price').val().length;
if(selectLength > 0 && textLength > 0) {
    jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled", false);
}
else {
  jQuery('#add-field').prop("disabled",true);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u96zT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup event to check the size of the value inside the input box.

```
$(#from-price').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length === 0 )
         $('#add-field').attr('disabled','disabled');
    else{
         $('#add-field').removeAttr('disabled'); 
         console.log($(this).val().length);
    }
});
```

If the input is generated dynamically, use `.on()` for capturing keyup.